# How to check if a pandas series contains "\"?

Tags: python, pandas, string

I have a pandas series `['\ufffa', 'abc']` and I would like to check if a string contains `\`. I try

```
import pandas as pd
tmp = ['\ufffa', 'abc']
tmp = pd.Series(tmp)
tmp.str.startswith('\\')
```

and it returns

```
0    False
1    False
dtype: bool
```

With a single string, I can use `r'\ufffa'.startswith('\\')`. Could you please elaborate on how to do so for a whole series?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your string doesn't start with a backslash.  `\ufffa` is a unicode escape and your string contains the unicode code point [U+FFFA](https://unicode-table.com/en/FFFA/) ("Interlinear Annotation Separator").

In your other example, you used `r'\ufffa'`, not `'\ufffa'`; you're using a raw string there, so the unicode escape doesn't take effect.  If you do the same in your DataFrame, then `startswith` with work as you expect there as well.

Comment: Can you explain how can I do for the whole dataframe (without using loop)?

Comment: @LEAnhDung: Do what?  The DataFrame doesn't really have anything to do with this.  The problem is that as soon as you write `tmp = ['\ufffa', 'abc']` you have created the string with U+FFFA in it.  There is no backslash in your string at any time.  If you do `print(tmp)` after creating the list (without even creating a DataFrame), you will see there is no backslash.  If you want to find a backslash you need to make sure there is a backslash when you first create the data.

Comment: This is because the strings are returns by `os.listdir(d)`. Do you have any suggestion to filter out those strings?

Comment: @LEAnhDung: If you're having problems with particular strings, then edit your question so it reproduces the actual problem you're having.